# Passing variable through PHP exec

Tags: php, exec

I am using the php `exec` command to execute another file.

I am using the following:

```
 exec ('php email.php');
```

But I would wish to pass a variable called $body to "email.php" file through the exec command. How can I pass the variable through exec command?

Comment: php calling php? why `exec()`? Any reason you couldn't just `include()` it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass the argument:

```
exec('php email.php "' . addslashes($body) . '"');
```

Get it in *email.php*:

```
$body = stripslashes($argv[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks. addslashes and strpslashes works perfect but $body = stripslashes($argv[1]) and not argv[0]

Comment: Indeed, `$argv[0]` is the file's name. I corrected it, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
 exec ('php email.php firstparameter secondparameter thirdparameter');
```

You can also refer this : [Command Line Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php)

Answer (score 4):

You can pass it as a parameter to `email.php`

```
exec('php email.php "'.addslashes($body).'"');
```

And `email.php` get it with

```
$body = stripslashes($argv[1]);
```

But if $body contains long text with fancy chars, it is better if you save it to a temporary file with random name.

```
<?php
$temp_file = uniqid().'.txt';
file_put_contents($temp_file, $body);
exec("php email.php $temp_file");
```

Then in `email.php`, get the `$body` from contents of `$temp_file`.

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to pass parameters to php script from php exec command:

```
<?php 
$fileName = '/var/www/ztest/helloworld.php 12';
$options = 'target=13';
exec ("/usr/bin/php -f {$fileName} {$options} > /var/www/ztest/log01.txt 2>&1 &");

echo "ended the calling script"; 
?>
```

see [complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14993436/1166727) (with called script and results)