# Error Code 1 Incorrect Function returned from php exec

Tags: php, bash

I'm running the following exec method in php.

```
exec("exec /bin/bash ./test.sh $file $fileY 2>&1", $output, $return);
```

However when I print out the $return variable I get 1 as a result which is an error code.

How do I diagnose this to find out why this error code is appearing, I've tried a number of different methods to figure it out like setting permissions for everything to 077 but none of it is working.

Can anyone advise me on what to do?

Comment: What is the result of `/bin/bash ./test.sh $file $fileY 2>&1 && echo $?`?

Comment: Do you mean adding `&& echo $? ` to the end of the first parameter of the exec method?

Comment: No ! executing it in the terminal is what I meant

Comment: This is an [\[ intersting read \]](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10768899/1620779) for this one as you're passing arguents.