# Passing variables from PHP to command line SVN

Tags: php, batch-file, cmd, tortoisesvn

I need to create a web app for a school project and need to use SVN. I  have a path in a PHP variable and iam using command line svn. So i need to pass that variable into batch file command. So how can I  store the value of PHP variable into the batch variable. please help.

My code

```
<?PHP
$vname="\project";
$svnpath="d:\a\svn";
$serverpath=$svnpath.$vname;
mkdir $serverpath;
exec("svnadmin create <server path value>");
?>
```

Comment: See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768751/passing-variable-throght-php-exec).If you still can't get it leave a comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing variable throght PHP exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768751/passing-variable-throght-php-exec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `exec("svnadmin create $serverpath")`. Interpreter will replace `$serverpath` with it's value just like in normal strings wrapped with `"`.

**For example:**

`echo 'svnadmin create $serverpath'` will output `svnadmin create $serverpath`

**However:**

`echo "svnadmin create $serverpath"` will output `svnadmin create d:\a\svn\project`

More information in [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).